# Generating 0 or 1 at random quickly

Tags: python

With python I am using random.randint(0,1) to generate a 0 or 1 at random. It is quite slow though because I need to do it about a billion times. Is there a quicker way?

```
total=0
n=1000000000
for x in range(n):
    money=2
    while True:
        x=random.randint(0,1)
        if x==1:
            break
        if x==0:
            money*=2
            continue
    total+=money
print(total/n)
```

Comment: Python can not repeat something a billion times effectively, or at least not without libraries like `numpy` that do the work on a C/C++ library.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem which language would you recommend for this?

Answer (score 4):

As already commented this will be somewhat slow in pure Python no matter what.

But the plain `random.random()` (which `random.randint()` is built on top of, albeit with surprising complexity) already returns a floating point value between 0.0 and 1.0 (or, more precisely, in the range `[0.0, 1.0)`), so if you want a random binary value with a reasonably stable distribution you can do something like

```
from random import random # Avoiding the module attribute access on each loop will save some time
...
if random() < 0.5:
    # do one thing
else:
    # do the other
```

I think even for 1e9 loops this will be acceptable. Otherwise you might try Cython.

Answer (score 3):

On Linux you can read from `/dev/urandom`:

```
from random import randint, getrandbits, random
from timeit import timeit
from operator import and_
from itertools import starmap

f_in = open('/dev/urandom', 'rb')

def generate_num1(n):
    return starmap(and_, zip(f_in.read(n), [1]*n))

def generate_num2(n):
    return (randint(0, 1) for _ in range(n))

def generate_num3(n):
    return (getrandbits(1) for _ in range(n))

def generate_num4(n):
    return (1 if random() < 0.5 else 0 for _ in range(n))

print(timeit(lambda: list(generate_num1(1024)), number=1000))
print(timeit(lambda: list(generate_num2(1024)), number=1000))
print(timeit(lambda: list(generate_num3(1024)), number=1000))
print(timeit(lambda: list(generate_num4(1024)), number=1000))
```

Prints (on my old laptop i3-3110, ubuntu 16.04):

```
0.11714126999140717
1.9653857139928732
0.20527600098284893
0.1918482400069479
```

---

UPDATE 27.2.2024 (AMD 5700x/Ubuntu 20.04/Python 3.11.7):

```py
0.020467253983952105
0.2510357769788243
0.033986544993240386
0.05389478203142062
```

Each of these 3 options is significantly faster than `random.randint`. `/dev/urandom` seems fastest.

Comment: I added `random.random()` and `random.getrandbits(1)` to this script. My test runs show that `random.random()` is the fastest of the four options.

Comment: @vastlysuperiorman update: I've played with various options, now `/dev/urandom` seems to be fastest

Comment: Very interesting! Thanks for the update. I realized after commenting, the float comparison `random() < 0.5` probably has an impact on performance, so I'm glad you added that into the test.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly faster solution would be to use `random.getrandbits(1)`

By the way, if you're wondering if your money loop will converge to a particular value, it will not.  The more sampling you do, the higher the average figure will get although it will vary a lot between runs, especially with a smaller number of loops.

Each iteration has 50% chance of returning 2, 25% chance of returning 4, 12.5% chance of returning 8, and so on ...

The mathematical expectancy can be expressed as a series (which does not converge):

∑ 2*1/2 + 4*1/4 + 8*1/8 .... == ∑ 2^p/2^p == 1 + 1 + 1 + ...

In other words a varying sum of 1s who's average will be higher and higher as you take more samples.

Since you're not making an infinite number of attempts, you will get an actual figure out of this.  Each of the powers of 2 (p) in the above series will average out to 1 until 2^p > n.  Then the expected values of the higher powers will start to drop.

For example, for 2^30 (roughly 1000000000), you will get an average of 1 for the first 30 powers of 2.  You will then get 0.5 for 2^31, 0.25 for 2^32, and so on.  This will add up to roughly 2 on top the first 30.  So, in theory, the average for n = 2^30 should be near 32.

More generally, this should give an average of 2 + log(n,2) which does not progress very rapidly but *will* reach infinity nontheless.

For example:

- 1 million --> log(1000000,2)+2 --> 21.9
- 100 million --> log(100000000,2)+2 --> 28.6
- 1 billion --> log(1000000000,2)+2 --> 31.9

There will be variation on small samples because outliers in the higher powers of two will randomly be hit and have a significant impact on the average.  The impact of these outliers is less perceptible when the number of samples is larger.

If what you're looking for is a way to generate a value with an exponential distribution, you may want to try random.expovariate() and use its value as an exponent of 2.

Comment: Well I heard it is supposed to go to infinity but I am only getting values in the 20s, even with 100 million samples. I am trying to see how quickly the average increases as I increase the number of samples (n). It seems to be worse than logarithmic

Comment: Hmm, why *"This will add up to roughly 2"*? I mean, *"0.5 for 2^31, 0.25 for 2^32, and so on"* diverges to infinity just as much. Sure, if you sample 2^30, then you'll get let's say the single result 2^40 only once in 1024 times you run the experiment, but when it does, it adds not 1 but 1024. For example, I just repeatedly ran the experiment with sample size 2^20 (where you'd calculate an average outcome of 22). After 59 runs of the experiment, the average outcome was 25.62. But then the outcome of the 60th run was 692.20, and that bumped up the average outcome to 36.73. The *median*, on...

Comment: ... the other hand, only increased from 23.16 to 23.22. I guess when we run the experiment the limited number of times our patience allows, what we observe rather relates to something like the median instead of the average...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this effectively with numpy. For more information on the numpy random functionality, see: [(link)](https://chrisalbon.com/python/basics/generating_random_numbers_with_numpy/). This returns a numpy array with the resulting random sequence.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

        np.random.randint(low=0, high=1, size=1000000000)
```

```
Out[2]: array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0])
```

Alternatively, you could use randbits as follows:

```
In [1]: from random import getrandbits
        nums = [not random.getrandbits(1) for i in range(0,100000)]
```

```
Out[2]: [False,True,...,False]
```

Comment: The OP doesn't know the size of his randint vector beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using numpy + iterators:

*I'm not sure what your speed is, but this execution takes 6 +/- 0.5 seconds.*

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(11)
n=0
total=0
while n<10**9:
    # 10**5 seems to be the golden number here
    n_vals = np.random.randint(0,2, 10**5)
    n+=10**5

    # The prevalence of zeros shouldn't be diff than that of ones
    n_zeros =  len(n_vals) - np.sum(n_vals)
    # square the value of money
    total += n_zeros*2

print(total/n)
# 1.000063652
```